# Moving files of specific type/extension from one directory to another?

Tags: bash, mkdir

Have a large folder filled with a large collection of different files.Ideally, I want to shift all the different files into their respective folders; so jpg files into the jpg folder etc.

Original folder : unsorted_files
destination folder: jpgfolder
I tried

```
mv /home/tony/Desktop/unsorted_files/*.jpg /home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder
```

But got an error "jpgfolder" is not  a directory"

Comment: you probably move the fist file to "/home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder" move it back. Then `makedir /home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder` and run `mv /home/tony/Desktop/unsorted_files/*.jpg /home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder/`

Comment: `mv` does not create folders. 1. `mkdir -p /home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder`; 2. `mv ...`

Comment: I know it doesn't, I already have created the destination folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking in account that 1) Q said "large collection ... of files" - the list of files might not all fit in one command line buffer (2,084,684 bytes on **MY** system); and 2) Filenames might contain funny characters ("`My Stuff.jpg`"); `mv` is not the best way. Using `find`, `xargs`, and the sure knowledge that filenames must NOT contain NUL bytes (or slashes):

```
find /home/tony/Desktop/unsorted_files/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty echo mv --target-directory=/home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder
```

Once the `echo`d commands look right, remove the `echo`, and let `mv` do the work.

If you have already done `mv /home/tony/Desktop/unsorted_files/*.jpg /home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder` **BEFORE** you created the `/home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder`, nothing has been lost, but you must, as other answers have said, `mkdir -p /home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder` first.

Comment: Read `man find`. Read `man xargs`. Try to state your confusion as a question.

Comment: @IronUhlan And add that question **here** instead of posting a new question with the same content!

Comment: Which I've already done.I did that because of the coding stuff.

Comment: `find ... -exec mv -t ... -- {} +` would be slightly more elegant than the detour through `xargs`, imho. Otherwise +1.

Comment: @david-foerster How does `find ... -exec mv -t ... -- {} +` handle too many filenames? `man find` says `The command line is built in much the same way that xargs builds its command lines.`, but that's unclear.

Comment: @waltinator: I think that's perfectly clear if you know how `xargs` handles more arguments than fit on the command-line. More importantly, it means that `xargs` isn't superior to `find -exec ... {} +` in this case.

Comment: @waltinator: I just [ran a test](https://gist.github.com/davidfoerster/6b845f84054f8cad28f3f82edb99535b) to confirm that `find -exec ... {} +` can deal with 1 million matches with a total path name length of over 256 MiB.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know - corrections are welcome - `mv` does not actually move files, it renames them. So you are trying to rename all jpg files to a folder name.

I would try:

```
rsync /home/tony/Desktop/unsorted_files/*.jpg /home/tony/Desktop/jpgfolder
```

Comment: while staying on the same filesystem, moving and renaming a file is exactly the same thing. `mv` is smart enough to know if the file should be moved to another filesystem or just renamed into another directory.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rQg59xu7

@waltinator, I have tried to implement your solution, but still the files are not being transferred